# Method Override in c# using mysql not working

Tags: c#, mysql, xampp

[image]

I have installed mysql connect v. 6.8.8, and added them in the reference..But when I method override mysqlconnection... it wont work... conn wont appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use it within a method or property.

Comment: can you give an example